# How do dynamically access a type via function parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have something like the following:

```
const activeFormDesign = {
    fields: {
    },
    elements: {
    },
    groups: {
    },
    layouts: {
        section: SectionLayout,
        header: Header,
        title: Title,
        description: Description,
        goal: Goal,
    },
};
```

Each property of `layouts` refers to a functional component with distinct props. My goal is that someone can access the FC of a given layout by providing the key, and the returned FC will know what props its supposed to have.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
export function getLayoutTemplate(type: keyof typeof activeFormDesignTemplate['layouts']): FC<typeof activeFormDesignTemplate['layouts'][type] {
    return activeFormDesignTemplate.layouts[type];

}

const Goal = getLayoutTemplate('goal');

<Goal />
```

The parameter type works great. But the return type throws an error that "type cannot be used as an index type". I mean... it kind of makes sense. I understand that a truly dynamic type couldn't be inferred. But if I'm statically typing it out, as in `getLayoutTemplate('goal')` I would think that it could.

I feel like there's a way to do this, but I've not quite figured it out and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `SectionLayout`, `Header`, etc. are already of type `React.FC`, you only need to make the function generic over `K` and remove the `React.FC` around the return type.

```
export function getLayoutTemplate<
  K extends keyof typeof activeFormDesign["layouts"]
>(type: K): typeof activeFormDesign['layouts'][K] {
    return activeFormDesign.layouts[type];
}
```

The parameter `type` is now of type `K` and you can use `K` to index `typeof activeFormDesign['layouts']` for the return type.

But you are gonna need to find a way at runtime to convert whatever `SectionLayout`, `Header`, etc. are into a `React.FC` if they are *not* already of type `React.FC`

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=25&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoCgEyTQBsUi40IA7AZ3gGVaZg2AMigCeEAK4wAXImIwAdADEAwgB4UrYQD5qtBkxYd4ACVQ0o05OnnK1G7eRr1GSZm05wAKsBh0kF2Yqq6lo6Tvpu8AAiSOxoUMBgfGz+VoG2IQ66zq6GcADiECh0KRhpwfYUBu5WwABuSArQINHswADmrHAAvHAA3hRwg3CYwEh0VOzS-eRDcAC+ADQDQ2NIIEisMJN9y4OLu3BtOGJg29Oz+zNDDKISZwez7Lz8rNI8GC9CtzBLV7ODAAtTEhzHATCgzL9-kM+D4-J5vL4odC4DRYvFEi9pC04gkkqxkdC2oVivkSYT5r85gBuCgUJAAD0gsGGYlYHzYhyQMC+4hgHjWYAYMCQKmWAGk4IyRawJnAANZIUSYOAwYRgJAQFU1eqNKDNGLtVgAbXwNz57HwAF0KJoABRqjXScUASmkjs12o+uqaLSNxoA5Oa7gGrcbxVadn84EQYGIoJ0dQ1fYaOnJg1tjR6rbTyHM6eQqvACkUAEzdLk8kR8gXgYVIO0B4lFAMu6lAA)

Comment: Thanks, Tobias! After some fiddling around that did it! I didn't think about how to use an inferred generic here. Clever!